# How to set a scale for the time series, current x scale gives me NaN?

Tags: d3.js

The d3 code which I used is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

svg {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}


.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.y.axis path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.brush .extent {
  stroke: #fff;
  fill-opacity: .125;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.line {
  fill: none;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var margin = {top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 100, left: 40},
    margin2 = {top: 430, right: 10, bottom: 20, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    height2 = 500 - margin2.top - margin2.bottom;

var color = d3.scale.category10();

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d %b %Y").parse;

var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]),
    x2 = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]),
    y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]),
    y2 = d3.scale.linear().range([height2, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom"),
    xAxis2 = d3.svg.axis().scale(x2).orient("bottom"),
    yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left");

var brush = d3.svg.brush()
    .x(x2)
    .on("brush", brush);

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .defined(function(d) { return !isNaN(d.points); })
    .interpolate("cubic")
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.Date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.points); });

var line2 = d3.svg.line()
    .defined(function(d) { return !isNaN(d.points); })
    .interpolate("cubic")
    .x(function(d) {return x2(d.Date); })
    .y(function(d) {return y2(d.points); });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
    .attr("id", "clip")
  .append("rect")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var focus = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var context = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin2.left + "," + margin2.top + ")");

d3.csv("nifty_50_data.csv", function(error, data) {
  color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "Date"; }));

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    // debugger;
    d.Date = parseDate(d.Date);
    d.Open = parseFloat(d.Open);
    d.High = parseFloat(d.High);
    d.Low = parseFloat(d.Low);
    d.Close = parseFloat(d.Close);
  });
  // console.log(data);
  var sources = color.domain().map(function(name) {
      return {
        name: name,
        values: data.map(function(d) {
          return {date: d.Date, points: +d[name]};
        })
      };
    });
    console.log(sources);
    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.Date; }));
    y.domain([d3.min(sources, function(c) { return d3.min(c.values, function(v) { return v.points; }); }),
              d3.max(sources, function(c) { return d3.max(c.values, function(v) { return v.points; }); }) ]);
    x2.domain(x.domain());
    y2.domain(y.domain());

    var focuslineGroups = focus.selectAll("g")
        .data(sources)
      .enter().append("g");

    var focuslines = focuslineGroups.append("path")
        .attr("class","line")
        .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); })
        .style("stroke", function(d) {return color(d.name);})
        .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");

    focus.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    focus.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis);

    var contextlineGroups = context.selectAll("g")
        .data(sources)
      .enter().append("g");

    var contextLines = contextlineGroups.append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", function(d) { return line2(d.values); })
        .style("stroke", function(d) {return color(d.name);})
        .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");

    context.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height2 + ")")
        .call(xAxis2);

    context.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x brush")
        .call(brush)
      .selectAll("rect")
        .attr("y", -6)
        .attr("height", height2 + 7);


});

function brush() {
  x.domain(brush.empty() ? x2.domain() : brush.extent());
  focus.selectAll("path.line").attr("d",  function(d) {return line(d.values)});
  focus.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
  focus.select(".y.axis").call(yAxis);
}

</script>
```

Data:

```
Date,Open,High,Low,Close
16 Nov 2018,10644.00,10695.15,10631.15,10682.20
15 Nov 2018,10580.60,10646.50,10557.50,10616.70
14 Nov 2018,10634.90,10651.60,10532.70,10576.30
13 Nov 2018,10451.90,10596.25,10440.55,10582.50
12 Nov 2018,10607.80,10645.50,10464.05,10482.20
09 Nov 2018,10614.70,10619.55,10544.85,10585.20
07 Nov 2018,10614.45,10616.45,10582.30,10598.40
06 Nov 2018,10552.00,10600.25,10491.45,10530.00
05 Nov 2018,10558.75,10558.80,10477.00,10524.00
02 Nov 2018,10462.30,10606.95,10457.70,10553.00
01 Nov 2018,10441.70,10441.90,10341.90,10380.45
31 Oct 2018,10209.55,10396.00,10105.10,10386.60
30 Oct 2018,10239.40,10285.10,10175.35,10198.40
29 Oct 2018,10078.10,10275.30,10020.35,10250.85
26 Oct 2018,10122.35,10128.85,10004.55,10030.00
25 Oct 2018,10135.05,10166.60,10079.30,10124.90
24 Oct 2018,10278.15,10290.65,10126.70,10224.75
23 Oct 2018,10152.60,10222.10,10102.35,10146.80
22 Oct 2018,10405.85,10408.55,10224.00,10245.25
19 Oct 2018,10339.70,10380.10,10249.60,10303.55
17 Oct 2018,10688.70,10710.15,10436.45,10453.05
16 Oct 2018,10550.15,10604.90,10525.30,10584.75
15 Oct 2018,10524.20,10526.30,10410.15,10512.50
12 Oct 2018,10331.55,10492.45,10322.15,10472.50
11 Oct 2018,10169.80,10335.95,10138.60,10234.65
10 Oct 2018,10331.85,10482.35,10318.25,10460.10
09 Oct 2018,10390.30,10397.60,10279.35,10301.05
08 Oct 2018,10310.15,10398.35,10198.40,10348.05
05 Oct 2018,10514.10,10540.65,10261.90,10316.45
04 Oct 2018,10754.70,10754.70,10547.25,10599.25
03 Oct 2018,10982.70,10989.05,10843.75,10858.25
01 Oct 2018,10930.90,11035.65,10821.55,11008.30
28 Sep 2018,11008.10,11034.10,10850.30,10930.45
27 Sep 2018,11079.80,11089.45,10953.35,10977.55
26 Sep 2018,11145.55,11145.55,10993.05,11053.80
25 Sep 2018,10969.95,11080.60,10882.85,11067.45
24 Sep 2018,11164.40,11170.15,10943.60,10967.40
21 Sep 2018,11271.30,11346.80,10866.45,11143.10
19 Sep 2018,11326.65,11332.05,11210.90,11234.35
18 Sep 2018,11381.55,11411.45,11268.95,11278.90
17 Sep 2018,11464.95,11464.95,11366.90,11377.75
14 Sep 2018,11443.50,11523.25,11430.55,11515.20
12 Sep 2018,11340.10,11380.75,11250.20,11369.90
11 Sep 2018,11476.85,11479.40,11274.00,11287.50
10 Sep 2018,11570.25,11573.00,11427.30,11438.10
07 Sep 2018,11558.25,11603.00,11484.40,11589.10
06 Sep 2018,11514.15,11562.25,11436.05,11536.90
05 Sep 2018,11514.85,11542.65,11393.85,11476.95
04 Sep 2018,11598.75,11602.55,11496.85,11520.30
03 Sep 2018,11751.80,11751.80,11567.40,11582.35
31 Aug 2018,11675.85,11727.65,11640.10,11680.50
30 Aug 2018,11694.75,11698.80,11639.70,11676.80
29 Aug 2018,11744.95,11753.20,11678.85,11691.90
28 Aug 2018,11731.95,11760.20,11710.50,11738.50
27 Aug 2018,11605.85,11700.95,11595.60,11691.95
24 Aug 2018,11566.60,11604.60,11532.00,11557.10
23 Aug 2018,11620.70,11620.70,11546.70,11582.75
21 Aug 2018,11576.20,11581.75,11539.60,11570.90
20 Aug 2018,11502.10,11565.30,11499.65,11551.75
17 Aug 2018,11437.15,11486.45,11431.80,11470.75
```

The x scale returns NaN values and I get only the axis plotted, but not the lines.

Could someone please point out what I am doing wrong here...

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from `line` and `line2` x functions where you give `d.Date` as argument but date has been defined with a lowercase key in the `source` object.

```
var line = d3.svg.line()
    .defined(function(d) { return !isNaN(d.points); })
    .interpolate("cubic")
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); }) // <-- change to lowercase date
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.points); });

var line2 = d3.svg.line()
    .defined(function(d) { return !isNaN(d.points); })
    .interpolate("cubic")
    .x(function(d) {return x2(d.date); }) // <-- change to lowercase date
    .y(function(d) {return y2(d.points); });
```